# How to pass this credentials to the WebView

Tags: iphone

I am using UIWebView and i have to load some URL to it. But the site requires userCredentials, I logged into this site in other ViewController. Now I have to pass this credentials to the WebView. How it possible??? URL is http://test.docphin.com/connect/download.aspx?ID=%d

If i directly load this link to webView it shows nothing,,,

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of this page? Then you can probably use javascript:
Use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScript method of the UIWebView. Using this method you can interact with the webview without reloading urls. I think you can pass credentials like this.

If not, then you need out the exact link that's pressed when clicking 'log in' and see if the credentials are passed using the headers or get-parameters.